# Viewpager inside NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I want to scroll viewpager and RecyclerView together in NestedScrollView. ViewPager is not scrolling with NestedScrollView. Here is my XML :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/scrollview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  tools:context="com.nobakhti.haidar.nosazimadares.MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
      android:id="@+id/indicator"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="15dp"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layoutDirection="ltr"
      tools:listitem="@layout/adapter_titles"
      android:id="@+id/news_title"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here attaching the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `NestedScrollView` using `CoordinatorLayout` Like this

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.nobakhti.haidar.nosazimadares.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

      android:id="@+id/scrollview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true">

      <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:layout_gravity="top"/>

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
          android:id="@+id/indicator"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="15dp"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layoutDirection="ltr"
          tools:listitem="@layout/adapter_titles"
          android:id="@+id/news_title"/>

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips . I made this change but the problem was not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Replace `NestedScrollView` with `ScrollView`. That should work.